# E: The package python3 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: upgrade, python3

I am in the process of upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 and this what I got:

```
E: The package python3 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

This is the output of `sudo apt --dry-run install --reinstall python3=3.8.2-0ubuntu2` ;

```
[sudo] password for ha: 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
E: The package python3 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: can you show us `apt --dry-run install --reinstall python3=3.8.2-0ubuntu2` please add the output to your question. This is only a simulation.